# How to set up Acumatica Locally with Xampp

Tags: xampp, acumatica

I have Xampp installed on my computer however whenever I try to go through the acumatica installer I get this error "Unknown system variable 'information_schema_stats_expiry'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xampp comes with MariaDB installed automatically. This is not compatible with acumatica. What you need to do is install mysql 5.7.6 on the xampp server. This guide helps a lot.
https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/1215/how-to-use-mysql-5-7-instead-of-mariadb-in-xampp-for-windows